# Failed to download laravel/spark-aurelius from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/laravel/spark-aurelius/zipball

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-spark

I am installing laravel spark under windows, installation via composer. when i get to the stage `compose update`  of the documentation i have this error:

> Failed to download laravel/spark-aurelius from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/laravel/spark-aurelius/zipball
> [RuntimeException]
> Failed to execute git clone --no-checkout "https://***:***@github.com/laravel/spark-aurelius.git" "C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\spark-aurelius" && cd /D "C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\spark-aurelius" && git remote add composer "https://***:***@github.com/laravel/spark-aurelius.git" && git fetch composer
> Cloning into 'C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\spark-aurelius'...  remote: Repository not found.
> fatal: repository 'https://***:***@github.com/laravel/spark-aurelius.git/' not found

Comment: Where did you find this package? It does not exist on packagist.

Comment: Have alook at https://spark.laravel.com/docs/6.0/installation#installation-via-composer

Comment: @rob006 
my boss had bought it and he had just provided me the key

Comment: @Nico Haase yes that's what I follow

Comment: And you've used it in your `composer.json`? Can you share it, redacting your private keys?

Comment: @NicoHaase 
yes I used at composer.json . to share it how?

Comment: Well, just add the content to the question

Comment: and if I have the zip packege how to pass?

Answer (score 12):

I also experienced this error.
The solution for me was:

1. Log into my Spark account
2. Click GitHub on the left
3. Connect to GitHub
4. Join both repositories
5. View each repostory and click the Accept
   button

Comment: Thanks. It was the view repository part I needed. I had already joined them but I did not view them, in order to accept the invitation.

Comment: Are you kidding me!? Not in a million years would I have figured this out! Thank you!!